# Calling different functions of a DLL from different threads simultaneously segfaults or gives a status_stack_buffer_overrun

Tags: rust, dll, ffi

I'm writing a library regarding Bridge (the card game), which performs deals generation, performance analysis and other stuff. I'm using Rust and, for some functionalities, I'm leaning on the DLL of a C++ library, called Double Dummy Solver (henceforth DDS - [Site](https://privat.bahnhof.se/wb758135/bridge/index.html), [GitHub](https://github.com/dds-bridge/dds)). I used `bindgen` to create the bindings for the DLL (I don't know if this is the correct approach: I am not a programmer by trade and I kinda had an hard time wrapping my head around how DLL and FFI works and how to use them in Rust. I'll happily accept advices regarding this.) and everything seemed to work perfectly.

After implementing a parallel function to analyse multiple deals simultaneously (AnalyseAllPlaysBin, [link to the docs](https://github.com/dds-bridge/dds/blob/develop/doc/DLL-dds_x.pdf)) and writing a little test for it, `cargo test` started failing with:

`exit code: 0xc0000409, STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN`
or with:

```
exit code: 0xc0000005, STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
note: test exited abnormally; to see the full output pass --nocapture to the harness.
Segmentation fault
```

I was a bit surprised and I dug a bit to understand the problem. I found out that the reason for the failure was `cargo` running the tests in parallel, and I think simultaneous calls mess up with the DLL, making it segfault.

Using `cargo t -- --test-threads=1` solves the problem, but since I'm writing a library I hope to use for an application in the future, I would like to understand the problem and solve it in some way. I'm not planning to make multiple simultaneous calls to the DLL but the problem still bothers me.
I cannot provide an MWE but I'll give some code for reference:

```rust
use dds::{
    deal, // The `deal` type the C++ library uses
    solvedPlays, // Type of the C++ library
    solvedPlay,  // Same as above
    playTraceBin, // Same as above
    playTracesBin, // Same as above
    PlayTraceBin, // Cards played for the deal to analyze
    PlayTracesBin, // Collection of PlayTraceBin for different deals
    SolvedPlays, // My wrapper around the C++ type
    SolvedPlay, // Same
    RankSeq, // Sequence of the rank (2,3,Q,K,A ecc.) of cards played
    RawDDSRef, // Trait (fn get_raw(&self)) for getting a ref to the underlying struct of the Rust wrapper types
    RawDDSRefMut, // Same as above, but mut (fn get_raw_mut(&mut self))
    AsRawDDS, // Same as above, but not a ref (fn as_raw(self))
    SuitSeq, // Sequence of suits of cards played
    Target,Mode,Solutions // Parameters used by the DLL
    MAXNOOFBOARDS,
};

const TRIES: usize = 200;
const CHUNK_SIZE: i32 = 10;


pub fn initialize_test() -> DealMock {
    DealMock {
        hands: [
            [8712, 256114688, 2199023255552, 2344123606046343168],
            [22528, 10485760, 79182017069056, 744219838422974464],
            [484, 1612185600, 1924145348608, 4611686018427387904],
            [1040, 268435456, 57415122812928, 1522216674051227648],
        ],
    }
}

pub trait PlayAnalyzer {
    /// Analyzes a single hand
    /// # Errors
    /// Will return an Error when DDS fails in some way.
    fn analyze_play<D: AsDDSDeal, C: AsDDSContract>(
        deal: &D,
        contract: &C,
        play: PlayTraceBin,
    ) -> Result<SolvedPlay, DDSError>;
    /// Analyzes a bunch of hands in paraller.
    /// # Errors
    /// Will return an Error when DDS fails in some way or the deals and contracts vecs have
    /// different length or their length doe
    fn analyze_all_plays<D: AsDDSDeal, C: AsDDSContract>(
        deals: Vec<&D>,
        contracts: Vec<&C>,
        plays: &mut PlayTracesBin,
    ) -> Result<SolvedPlays, DDSError>;
}

impl PlayAnalyzer for DDSPlayAnalyzer {
    #[inline]
    fn analyze_all_plays<D: AsDDSDeal, C: AsDDSContract>(
        deals: Vec<&D>,
        contracts: Vec<&C>,
        plays: &mut PlayTracesBin,
    ) -> Result<SolvedPlays, DDSError> {
        let deals_len = i32::try_from(deals.len().clamp(0, MAXNOOFBOARDS)).unwrap();
        let contracts_len = i32::try_from(contracts.len().clamp(0, MAXNOOFBOARDS)).unwrap();

        if deals_len != contracts_len || deals_len == 0 || contracts_len == 0 {
            return Err(RETURN_UNKNOWN_FAULT.into()); // The error tells that
                // either something went terribly wrong or we used wrongly sized inputs.
        }

        let mut c_deals: Vec<deal> = contracts
            .into_iter()
            .zip(deals)
            .map(|(contract, deal)| construct_dds_deal(contract, deal))
            .collect();
        c_deals.resize(
            MAXNOOFBOARDS,
            deal {
                trump: -1,
                first: -1,
                currentTrickSuit: [-1i32; 3],
                currentTrickRank: [-1i32; 3],
                remainCards: [[0u32; 4]; 4],
            },
        );
        let mut boards = boards {
            noOfBoards: deals_len,
            // We know vec has the right length
            deals: match c_deals.try_into().unwrap(),
            target: [Target::MaxTricks.into(); MAXNOOFBOARDS],
            solutions: [Solutions::Best.into(); MAXNOOFBOARDS],
            mode: [Mode::Auto.into(); MAXNOOFBOARDS],
        };
        let mut solved_plays = SolvedPlays {
            solved_plays: solvedPlays {
                noOfBoards: deals_len,
                solved: [solvedPlay::new(); MAXNOOFBOARDS],
            },
        };

        let bop: *mut boards = &mut boards;
        let solved: *mut solvedPlays = solved_plays.get_raw_mut();
        let play_trace: *mut playTracesBin = (*plays).get_raw_mut();

        // SAFETY: calling C
        let result = unsafe { AnalyseAllPlaysBin(bop, play_trace, solved, CHUNK_SIZE) };
        match result {
            // RETURN_NO_FAULT == 1i32
            1i32 => Ok(solved_plays),
            n => Err(n.into()),
        }
    }

    #[inline]
    fn analyze_play<D: AsDDSDeal, C: AsDDSContract>(
        deal: &D,
        contract: &C,
        play: PlayTraceBin,
    ) -> Result<SolvedPlay, DDSError> {
        let c_deal = construct_dds_deal(contract, deal);
        let mut solved_play = SolvedPlay::new();
        let solved: *mut solvedPlay = &mut solved_play.solved_play;
        let play_trace = play.as_raw();
        // SAFETY: calling an external C function
        let result = unsafe { AnalysePlayBin(c_deal, play_trace, solved, 0) };
        match result {
            1i32 => Ok(solved_play),
            n => Err(n.into()),
        }
    }
}

/// Constructs a DDS deal from a DDS contract and a DDS deal representation
fn construct_dds_deal<D: AsDDSDeal, C: AsDDSContract>(contract: &C, deal: &D) -> deal {
    let (trump, first) = contract.as_dds_contract();
    deal {
        trump,
        first,
        currentTrickSuit: [0i32; 3],
        currentTrickRank: [0i32; 3],
        remainCards: deal.as_dds_deal().as_slice(),
    }
}


#[test]
fn analyse_play_test() {
    let deal = initialize_test();
    let contract = ContractMock {};
    let suitseq = SuitSeq::try_from([0i32, 0i32, 0i32, 0i32]).unwrap();
    let rankseq = RankSeq::try_from([4i32, 3i32, 12i32, 2i32]).unwrap();
    let play = PlayTraceBin::new(suitseq, rankseq);
    let solvedplay = DDSPlayAnalyzer::analyze_play(&deal, &contract, play).unwrap();
    assert_eq!([2, 2, 2, 2, 2], solvedplay.solved_play.tricks[..5]);
}

#[test]
fn analyse_all_play_test() {
    let mut deals_owner = Vec::with_capacity(TRIES);
    deals_owner.resize_with(TRIES, initialize_test);
    let deals = deals_owner.iter().collect();
    let suitseq = SuitSeq::try_from([0, 0, 0, 0]).unwrap();
    let rankseq = RankSeq::try_from([4, 3, 12, 2]).unwrap();
    let mut suitseqs = Vec::with_capacity(TRIES);
    let mut rankseqs = Vec::with_capacity(TRIES);
    suitseqs.resize_with(TRIES, || suitseq.clone());
    rankseqs.resize_with(TRIES, || rankseq.clone());
    let contracts_owner = Vec::from([ContractMock {}; TRIES]);
    let contracts = contracts_owner.iter().collect();
    let mut plays = PlayTracesBin::from_sequences(suitseqs, rankseqs).unwrap();
    let solved_plays = DDSPlayAnalyzer::analyze_all_plays(deals, contracts, &mut plays).unwrap();
    let real_plays = solved_plays.get_raw();
    assert_eq!(TRIES, real_plays.noOfBoards.try_into().unwrap());
    for plays in real_plays.solved {
        assert_eq!([2, 2, 2, 2, 2], plays.tricks[..5]);
    }
}
```

I could wrap the `DDSAnalyzer` in an `Arc<Mutex<_>>` and then lock it for the duration of the external function call. I think this should work (didn't have time to try it) but I don't know if it is the correct approach.

I would like to ask two things:

1. Why I get those errors in a multithreaded situation?
2. Would using a `Arc<Mutex<DDSAnalyzer>>` work? Is it the correct solution or should I do something different?

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Certainly does sound like these functions are not threadsafe - likely due to unsynchronized global state. Using a `Mutex` can be the solution but only if you limit the construction of `DDSAnalyzer` so that only one can exist. Otherwise if two got constructed you could hit the same problem.

Comment: Ok, clear, thanks! So I should use something like a `OnceLock`, correct?

Comment: @TheVava A OnceLock doesn't quite sound like what I'd expect here - it only lets you access it for write *once*. I don't know enough about this library, but if it's ok to have a single DDSPlayAnalyzer for the lifetime of the program, you could instead look into [putting it into a `OnceCell<Mutex<...>>`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/#lazy-initialized-global-data).

Comment: @nanofarad thanks! Yes, it should be ok to have just one `DDSPlayAnalyzer`. I was thinking about taking an approach similar to `std::io::stdin()` with something like this: `static RAWDDSANALYZER: OnceLock<Mutex<DDSPlayAnalyzerRaw>> = OnceLock::new();
        Self {
            inner: RAWDDSANALYZER.get_or_init(|| Mutex::new(DDSPlayAnalyzerRaw {})),
        }
`. Besides, you linked to `once_cell::sync::OnceCell`, which, if I'm not mistaken, was included in the standard library as `OnceLock`, so i think we are referring to the same type.

Comment: @TheVava Yes, my bad - OnceCell is very new in the standard library and I hadn't realized it was added. I believe it has the same behavior as the one I linked, and your code looks conceptually correct for what I was thinking - I'd encourage you to test it out, and if it works, [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with that code so that it's available for future readers and you're credited with it.

Comment: @nanofarad Thank you very much for the support! I tested the code and everything is back to working smoothly. I self-answered the question too! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by kmdreko the problem is that the DLL's functions are not threadsafe, probably due to unsynchronized global state.
Thanks to his and nanofarad suggestions (and a recent quick glance at [`std::io::stdin()` source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/io/stdio.rs.html#322-329)), I solved the issue by wrapping the struct which calls the functions in a `Mutex<StructThatActuallyCallsDLL>` to hold a lock to it while calling the function (so we do not get other threads trying to call the DLL's function while another thread is already running it) and using a `OnceLock` to initialize the struct managing the DLL only once and get a `'static` reference to it:

```rust
struct DDSPlayAnalyzer {
    inner: &'static Mutex<DDSAnalyzerRaw>
}

impl DDSPlayAnalyzer {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        static RAWDDSANALYZER: OnceLock<Mutex<DDSPlayAnalyzerRaw>> = OnceLock::new();
        Self {
            inner: RAWDDSANALYZER.get_or_init(|| Mutex::new(DDSPlayAnalyzerRaw {})),
        }
    }
}
```

and then implementing the correct Trait for `DDSAnalyzer` by locking and then calling the function on the contained `DDSAnalyzerRaw`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! This (static ref in the struct) is a pattern that I have not seen or used before, so I'm glad to have come across it here.